# How to count the number of non highlighted entries in a row on excel or sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to analyze a spreadsheet of multiple choice questions, I have a key and the incorrect answers are highlighted in yellow, I'm looking for a way to count the number of correct answers in each row, I've been trying by transferring over to sheets and  running this code;

```
/**
 * Counts the number of items with a given background.
 *
 * @param {String} color The hex background color to count.
 * @param {String} inputRange The range of cells to check for the background color.
 * @return {Number} The number of cells with a matching background.
 */
function countBackground(color, inputRange) {
  var inputRangeCells = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(inputRange);
  var rowColors = inputRangeCells.getBackgrounds();
  var count = 0;

  for(var r = 0; r < rowColors.length; r++) {
    var cellColors = rowColors[r];
    for(var c = 0; c < cellColors.length; c++) {
      if(cellColors[c] == color) {
        count++;
      }
    }
  }

  return count;
}
```

The issue is that I have several hundred tests and for some reason the range doesn't change when the cell values change.
Pictures of what I'm trying to score by row

[Picture of the sheet format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSbFp.png)
[Picture of the excel format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uRb2Z.png)

Comment: do you have a worksheet_change function that calls this?  If you want to detect when cells change you need to do that.  You don't want to stick the formula in a cell because then it will never refresh because the contents of that cell didn't change.  I wonder if using something like offer to calculate the input rage would make it more volatile...

Comment: This looks like it's related to Sheets, not Excel.

Comment: I'll add that for data clarity I would strongly recommend you implement a "Correct/Incorrect" column rather than merely storing vital information in a highlight.

Comment: Do you want to implement this as a custom function? Does each row have the exact same number of questions? Could you share a copy of the spreadsheet you are working on?

Answer (score 0):

**Highlighted Cells and the number of non highlighted cells on a Sheet**

I'd recommend that you delete most of the rows on a sheet before running this.

```
function countCells() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getActiveSheet();
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,1,sh.getMaxRows(),sh.getMaxColumns());
  var bA=rg.getBackgrounds();
  var ui=SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  var nhlA=[];
  var n=0;
  var resp=ui.prompt('Default Background Dialog',"Using hex code like '#ffffff' please enter the default background color" ,ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
  if(resp.getSelectedButton()==ui.Button.OK) {
    var dflt=resp.getResponseText();
    for(var i=0;i<bA.length;i++) {
      for(var j=0;j<bA[i].length;j++) {
        if(bA[i][j]!=dflt) {
          nhlA.push(sh.getRange(i+1,j+1).getA1Notation());
        }else{
          n++;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  var s=Utilities.formatString('Highlight Cells: %s <br />The Number of Non HighLighted cells: %s',nhlA.join(', '),n)
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(s);
  ui.showModelessDialog(userInterface, 'Non Highlight Cells')
}
```